# How to set the tab bar badge with swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am new in swift and I do not understand why this does not work correctly.

I have been reading similar questions but I have not found it.

I have a Tab Bar Controller with 4 Tabs and I need show a Badge with the text "New" in the tab with position 3, but with my code I only get one item, even though I have 4.

Does not recognize my tabs, so something I am doing bad.

It should be very easy, but I do not know the problem.

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!{
             let tabItem = tabItems[2] as! UITabBarItem
             tabItem.badgeValue = "New"
        }
}
```

And it throws this error:

> 2018-01-05 11:34:22.121749+0100 schoolnote[9774:574213] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds
>   [0 .. 0]'

Could you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: How many items in your tabBar? It looks like it is less than 3

Answer (score -1):

I assume that there is no need to cast `items` as `NSArray` since it's a `[UITabBarItem]`, thus there is also no need to cast `tabItems[2]` as `UITabBarItem`, it would be by default a `UITabBarItem`.

You could make it simpler, by implementing:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2].badgeValue = "New"
}
```

Note that this code should be implemented in the first (initial) view controller of the tabbar view controllers (the left selected on screen shot below), or you have to tap the desired tabbar item to display the view controller that has the above code. That should let the third item has a badge with "New" text in it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your question, but I tried this and I get the same error.

Comment: @BelenDominguezGarcia please make sure that you are implementing this in the *first* view controller of the tabbar view controllers.

Comment: You're right. My problem was that I do not place the code in the correct controller.
Now it works correctly

But with this I have a problem, I have a variable that is a counter (notifications counter) and I want that when this variable will be != 0, appears New on the itmem.

Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: You will be better off removing the update of the badge buttons from the view controllers and perhaps subclassing the UITabBarController itself to handle that.  Doing that you don't care which view controller might be active at any time.